# How to test email verification flow with dynamic email generation and get email data in automation?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am facing a problem with registration and login flow where it is required to generate an email and get token for verification. I need a service which allows user to generate n numbers of disposable emails with email data access that can self-destructs max 24 hours. Could anyone please share the service code to use in selenium java automation?

Comment: If you deploy your app under test in local infrastructure you can use [GreenMail](https://www.webelement.click/en/greenmail_setup_mock_to_test_emailing_with_greenmail) server to get the full control over your email traffic

Answer (score 2):

> The QA teams leave such tasks for manual testing instead of writing automation tests for these scenarios. \

But, all communication from the email can be automated by the disposable email service. This article will describe how to use this service within the automation suite using Nightwatch.js (Node).

[Registration and Login automation](https://docs.mail7.io/tutorials/registration-and-login-automation-using-selenium-with-disposable-email)

You can use this code as well to automate such things:

**2. Write down the logic of getEmail in common-function class and add dependencies in pom.xml file :**

```
<dependency>



<groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>



<artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>



<version>1.4.9</version>



</dependency>
```

We will use Unirest for handling the Mail7 API code. it is a set of lightweight HTTP libraries available in multiple languages, built and maintained by Mashape, who also maintain the open-source API Gateway Kong.

> Create a mail7.java file with below code

```
import org.apcahe.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;



public class mail7{



private static final String EMAIL-DOMAIN = ‘mail.io’;

private static final String EMAIL_APIKEY = ‘mail7_api_key’;

private static final String EMAIL_APISecret = ‘mail7_api_secret’;

private String emailid;



public usernameGenerator(){



String username = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8).toLowerCase();

System.out. println(“Random Username is ” + username);

return username;

}



public getInbox(String username){



HttpResponse <String> httpResponse = Unirest.get(“"https://api.mail7.io/inbox?apikey=" + EMAIL_APIKEY + "&apisecret=" + EMAIL_APISecret + "&to=" + username”)

.asString();

System.out.println( httpResponse.getHeaders().get("Content-Type"));

System.out.println(httpResponse.getBody());

return httpResponse.getBody();



}
```

**3. Create a class file for Test Script of Register and Login event** :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;



public class TestEmail throws IOException, UnirestException

{



public static void main(String[] args) {



//create a Selenium WebDriver instance

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","dir_path\\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();



//launch the Firefox browser and navigate to the website

driver.get(“YOUR_TEST_URL");



//puts an implicit wait for 10 seconds before throwing exceptions

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



//locate the email field

WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));



// create a random email address



String username = usernameGenerator();



String emailID = username.concat(“@”+EMAIL_DOMIAN);



//set the field's value

email.sendKeys(emailID);



//locate the password field

WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));



//set the password's value

password.sendKeys("password");



//locate and click the submit button

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();



//check if the mail has been received or not

String response = getInbo(username );



if(response.isEmpty()) {

System.out.println("Test not passed");

}else {

System.out.println("Test passed");

}



//close the Firefox browser.

driver.close();

}

}

}

}
```